# What corrections (e.g. errata updates) have been made to the official 5e Spellbook Cards, and what errors have not yet been fixed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, tools, errata

The official 5e [Spellbook Cards](https://wpn.wizards.com/en/products/dd-spellbook-cards) by Gale Force 9 did not include errata rules updates in their original printings, and I'm told they contained some errors as well. Has the most recent printing of these cards solved these problems? To what extent? Is there a corrected version of these cards?

Comment: @Timi: The latest PHB errata as of 2019 is here: http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf

Comment: That version of the errata labels itself version 2.0, just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 10):

## The cards are probably not edited with errata changes.

The original 2014 printing was redone in 2015, mostly to address rounding the corners on sharp cornered v1 cards and also to add an indication of whether a spell was concentration or not (that had apparently been omitted from the info on the cards in v1). Even by then, errata were being compiled and corrected for the core books, but I find no official word on those updates ever being considered by GF9 when updating the cards. If it were me in charge of it, that certainly would have happened.

If you want to use spellbook cards and you must be absolutely certain the cards incorporate all the necessary and most up to date text, you may need to create your own, or use some resources online to help you do so.

What follows is information gathered online, decide for yourself how reliable any of it really is.

---

[GF9 has an official online store page for those cards.](https://www.flamesofwar.com/Default.aspx?tabid=287&CategoryID=13327&PageIndex=2)  Most of the currently available sets are designated "2018 edition" in the online store, though there's no statement about how often they create new editions, exactly what is updated in each edition, or how to distinguish one edition from another (note on the bottom next to the UPC code, also cover art is different) when ordering from other sources.

[The Arcane cards](https://dnd.gf9games.com/gameAcc/tabid/87/entryid/92/spellbook-cards-arcane-73915.aspx) claim to now include spells from the SCAG, so the deck was updated since the first PHB printing, but not necessarily in ways indicated by the PHB errata.

There's no mention of errata or which PHB printing the card text is based on, so Gale Force 9 doesn't make a clear assertion that the 2018 edition incorporates errata. They are adding spells to some decks as well as adding blank DIY cards, and that seems to be what constitutes the update.

The cards for Xanathar’s Guide to Everything contain spells previously released in the Elemental Evil deck. There are some differences in some spells that could be considered errata corrections.

---

Several Amazon reviews for the Arcane deck assert the errata document wasn't considered in the 2018 update to the cards, but the reliability of the reviews are open to question. No photos of known errors either present or corrected in the cards are offered as proof.

---

Ted at Nerd Immersion on Youtube has a [review/unboxing](https://youtu.be/miestePy3ck) of the "version 3" cards released in 2018. There are a lot of updates, but Ted's review doesn't ask or answer the question of whether errata were considered in the version updates.

---

In this [unboxing video](https://youtu.be/TcDqVJjv4Lw?t=433) the Acid Splash card is clearly shown. It does not have the change in wording from the 2018 2.0 version of the errata. It looks like a version 3 deck, because the box art image is in portrait orientation, v1 and v2 had landscape orientation covers. It's possible the version 3 deck includes corrections from the [1.22 version of the errata from 2017](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) (which would not have a change for Acid Splash ) but I am not very hopeful.